# Is there a way in node.js to alter an existing file's byte data?

Tags: node.js, byte, buffer

For some reason, JPG images in my company are stored with the first two bytes changed (very crude encryption?).

I need to open them in node.js to resize and watermark them. I got as far as reading the image file into a ReadStream but that appears to be the wrong approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to get the Raw Binary string? If yes, were you able to manipulate it like a normal string with string functions?

Comment: `fs.readFile('a.jpg', function (err, buf) { if (err) throw err; /* edit buf here */ })`, see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html and https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html.

Comment: Joseph Dykstra, this works!  Thanks.